# Infill rows with 10 day rolling average - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, fill

I have a dataframe whereby some columns have 2 years of data while others have only a few months

I'm looking to infill the rest of the 2 years for the data with only a few months data with a 10day rolling average

```
df
            A  B  C  D  E
01/01/2021  2  4  3  2  1
.
.
.
01/08/2021 9  9  4  2  9
02/08/2021 8  8 NaN NaN NaN
03/08/2021 8 1 NaN NaN NaN
```

So ideally the NaN would be filled with the 10 day rolling average of the previous data

Would this be possible?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: do you have periods where more than 10 nan are following dates?

Comment: You could use `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` to fill the NaN values

Comment: @Ben.T yes, it would reach a point where there has been no data and it would have to just roll from the already inferred data i.e. eventually it would just be one constant value as no new data has been provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for anyone looking for a similar answer;

It gets tricky when there isn't consistent data to sample, i.e. it is sampling data it is generating itself.

```
null_cols = ['A','C','D']
while df.loc[:, null_cols].isnull().any().any():
    df.loc[:, null_cols] = df.loc[:, null_cols].fillna(df.loc[:, null_cols].rolling(10, min_periods=1).mean())
```